# flutter Horizontal Scrolling image and widget

Tags: dart, flutter

How can i make like this Horizontal Scrolling widget with image inside ?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 2):

```
ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, // <-- Like so
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.orange,
    ),
  ],
)
```

Code is based from flutter's [docs](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list)